# Does flutter wasm support native module import?

Tags: android, flutter, webassembly

I'm trying to use Android Native Module on Flutter web(by WASM), and create Android module and imported on flutter app.

It works on Android app but not on browser.

`android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flutter_application_1/MainActivity.kt`

```kotlin
package com.example.flutter_application_1

import kotlin.random.Random
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "example.com/channel").setMethodCallHandler {
            call, result ->
            if(call.method == "getRandomNumber") {
                val rand = Random.nextInt(100)
                result.success(rand)
            }
            else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`lib/main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  static const platform = MethodChannel('example.com/channel');
  Future<void> _generateRandomNumber() async {
    int random;
    try {
      random = await platform.invokeMethod('getRandomNumber');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      random = 0;
    }
    setState(() {
      _counter = random;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Kotlin generates the following number:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _generateRandomNumber,
        tooltip: 'Generate',
        child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On Browser, this error continuously occured, but not on mobile(on Android, but not tested on iOS)

[image]

I wonder that flutter WASM not yet supports the Native module importing.